# Rails: creating a feature spec to test a form that has a file upload field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, tdd, capybara, bdd

How are people handling the following situation: 
I have a form that takes an image. How do I verify whether or not the image was accepted? Or is this not something you should verify at this level of testing?

```
scenario "add facebook like gate and save as draft" do
  path =  "#{Rails.root}/app/assets/images/like_gate.jpg"

  visit root_url
  click_link I18n.t(:create_a_new_promotion)
  fill_in I18n.t(:title), with: "My promotion"
  click_button I18n.t(:continue)

  expect(page).to have_text(I18n.t(:promotion_details))
  expect(page).to have_text("My promotion")

  fill_in I18n.t(:like_gate_copy), with: "Like our page to enter the contest!"
  attach_file I18n.t(:upload_lg_image), path
  click_button I18n.t(:save_as_draft)

  expect(page).to have_text(I18n.t(:promotion_successfully_saved))
end
```

Is there a particular way to verify that `attach_file` was actually successful?
Also, how are people testing file uploads in general? In your request specs, controller specs and model specs? I'd like to stick to RSpec and Capybara for all my testing.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `attach_file` is a capybara method, don't test it.

Instead consider how valid/invalid uploads change your system state. If uploading a user avatar, for example, verify the user model has a pointer to the ID of the image you just uploaded. If you're doing an even higher level test, verify that a user sees the uploaded image (the url) where they'd expect to see it on the page.

In short, don't test image uploading, test the results of it.

`expect(page).to have_selector("img[src=#{path}]")`